# Minimum distance between holes in inner tube

Tags: road-bike, wheels, innertube, puncture

I recently got a second puncture in my road bike inner tube. In my opinion, the hole is pretty close to the other one that I fixed. I searched the internet but nowhere could I find a guideline to see what is the minimum recommended distance between two holes to fix them.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks in advance
Daan

Comment: I would recommend to buy some decent puncture proof tires instead of patching. Those tires can go for more than 10000km without a single puncture, it's something like a 100x reduction as far as I can tell. Definitely worth a few Euros/Dollars/whatever extra cost on the tires, imho.

Comment: @cmaster Sometimes the puncture is a sheer (un)luck and/or wrong inflation strategy. I had a trip where I patched daily. Very same bike, tyres, tubes, riding style year later and I didn't need to patch at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patches that overlap are less likely to work - even more so if they're those blunt-edged ones.   Thin patches that taper off gently will be more likely to work when overlapped.

Two patches overlapped may also cause an excessive bump, so I might take off the existing patch and fit the bigger size patch over both holes.

On one rare tube I ended up making a patch using a large piece of inner tube from a donor tube, and formed a homemade patch from that, which worked adequately.

So there is no minimum distance, it comes down to whether you can get a patch to adhere properly around the hole/s.

Answer (score 9):

If you can put a patch on without overlapping the existing one, it's fine. If the patches would overlap, I can't see any problem but I could have missed something.

Were the two punctures in rapid succession? If so, that and the similar location suggests that there's still debris in your tyre: check the area carefully for glass or similar pokng through the inside of the tyre.

Comment: Thanks, the time between two punctures was over two months so I don't think it was any debris. But still thanks!

Comment: @DaanHermans Agreed — it’d be more like two hours in that case. 